# Drupal: Set separate maximum/required number of values for a field, per role

Tags: drupal

For example:

- content-type: Gallery
- Imagefield: Gallery Images
- minimum of 3 values (so that 3 values will display on the form initially)
- maximum of 12 values if site member
- maximum of unlimited if site editor

Is this possible, or is there any existing module(s) that could help with the above? Thanks for any advice :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried them, but both the [User Quota](http://drupal.org/project/user_quota) and [Node Limit Number](http://drupal.org/project/node_limitnumber) modules supposedly do what you're looking for.